# How to Average Numbers from Command Line in Java

Tags: java, double, average

This is a school assignment. I truly want to understand what I am doing. We are instructed to make a program in Java that runs from the command line. After a user enters numbers the program should then start, send a welcome message, and then tell the user what the average of his numbers is.

I believe the point of this is to illustrate how `args` is used in the program and to help familiarize us with Java.

This is the explanation I have currently. I can run this from the command line, I know how to add a welcome message as well... But I do not understand the code well enough to be able to add in the ability to average the numbers when a user adds the arguments.

```
public class ArgumentExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        if( args.length == 1 || args.length > 1 ){
            System.out.println( args[0]);
        }

        if( args.length > 1 ) {
            for( int i = 1; i < args.length; i++ ){
                System.out.println(args[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class ArgumentExample {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            int i = 0; // declare a counter here so you can use it in the catch
            double tot = 0.0d; // declare the accumulator variable
            try {
                for (i = 0; i < args.length; i++) { // iterate over arguments...if only one is present returns just that one
                    tot += Double.parseDouble(args[i]); // sum
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                System.out.println("Argument " + i + " is not a number");// print which argument is not a number if any
            }
            System.out.println("Sum is: " + tot/(args.lenght == 0 ? 1 : args.lenght); // final print statement
        }
    }
```

Comment: Would you please explain the d after 0.0d Also If there was a specific reason you made the variable tot... did that stand for something in your head or was it just something you used? I just want to try and wrap my head around the whole thing. Thanks a ton.

Comment: the "d" declares explicitely the constant as double. You can use an "f" for float as well. I declared tot to store the progressive sum which would have been overwritten if declared in the for loop.

Comment: grrrrrr you added the numbers together... I looked at this all night turned it in online then realized it was just adding them... I can not believe it. Jokes on me yay... thanks...

Comment: System.out.println("Sum is: " + tot/args.length); // final print statement
        }    //you did not add the args.length

Comment: Yes i forgot the division...but look at the edit now. Your line will horribly fail in case of 0 arguments. Anyway, good luck with your future assignments if it took all night to spot a missing division in an trivial average operation....

Comment: so your recent edit is correct even with 0 arguments it will run?

Comment: Yes that one is a ternary if.

Answer (score 1):

Right now you are simply printing out the arguments that are put into the `args` array for you. It's not a big step from there to transforming the `String` arguments into numbers (say, doubles), adding those to a running sum in the loop, and dividing by the number of arguments after the loop:

```
    double sum = 0;
    if (args.length >= 1) {
        for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
            sum += Double.parseDouble(args[i]);
        }
        System.out.println("Average = " + sum/args.length);
    }
```

Double is the wrapper class for the primitive type double. It has the convenient method `parseDouble` to which you can pass a `String` and it will try to convert it to a `double` type. We should use doubles here instead of ints because of the higher precision of doubles - e.g. if you divide 5/2 you get 2, not 2.5, unless you make sure the 5 and 2 are treated as doubles.

Note that this has no error checking so it will fail by throwing an exception if any of the arguments is not parseable to a Double.

Comment: you're not considering the first arg. args index is 0-based

Comment: Ah, forgot to change the starting index. Thanks for that!

Answer (score 1):

`args` is a reference to the `String` array that holds all of the arguments passed into the program when it is started.

Arrays use a 0 base system for referencing the object in that position, so `args[0]` is the first argument passed to the program.

The `for( int i = 1; i < args.length; i++ )` loop
is going through the array until it reaches the end `( i = length - 1 )` after printing each argument

Answer (score 1):

Students tend to put too much stuff into main.

I'd recommend that you put the real work into sensible methods that you might use someday and pass data in and out, like this:

```
public class StatisticsUtils {
    public double average(double [] values) {
        double average = 0.0;
        if ((values != null) && (values.length > 0)) {
            for (double value : values) {
                average += value;
            }
            average /= values.length; 
        }
        return average;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the average of the numbers you have to build the sum of them and then divide through the number of arguments. For example

```
public class ArgumentExample 
{
  public static void main(String[] args) {

  int sum = 0;

  // step through all arguments
  for(String arg : args)
  {
    try
    {
      // try to convert the argument to an integer
      int number = Integer.parseInt(arg);
      // sum it
      sum += integer;
    }
    catch(NumberFormatException e)
    {
      // the currently processed argument couldn't be converted
      // to a number
      System.out.println(arg + " is not a number");
    }
  }

  // average = sum / valuecount
  double average = sum / args.length;

  System.out.println("average = " + average);
}
```

java -jar ArgumentExample 1 2 3 4 5 would result into 3. Hope that helps